# How to prove that the maximal eigenvalue of a matrix is $ \max\left\{ x^{T}Ax\thinspace|\thinspace x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},x^{T}x=1\right\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix. How can I prove that $$ \max\left\{ x^{T}Ax\thinspace|\thinspace x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},x^{T}x=1\right\}  $$

Is the biggest eigenvalue of $ A $?

After reading the hints from the comments:

Say $ v_{1},...,v_{n} $ is an orthogonal basis composed of eigenvectors of $A$ and each $v_i$ correspond to an eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Then for any eigenvector $x $ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have

$ Ax=\lambda x $

So that $$ A\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{<x,v_{k}>}{||v_{k}||^{2}}v_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{<x,v_{k}>}{||v_{k}||^{2}}Av_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{<x,v_{k}>}{||v_{k}||^{2}}\lambda_{k}v_{k}=\lambda x=\underset{k=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\lambda\frac{<x,v_{k}>}{||v_{k}||^{2}}v_{k} $$

So that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{<x,v_{k}>}{||v_{k}||^{2}}\lambda_{k}-\lambda\frac{<x,v_{k}>}{||v_{k}||^{2}}\right)v_{k}=0 $

How do I proceed?

Comment: Hint: Expand $x$ in an orthonormal eigenbasis (guaranteed to exist by the spectral theorem).

Comment: Hint: When $A$ is symmetric, all its eigenvalues are real. The members of the set need not be eigen vectors, just remember eigenvectors form a complete basis for whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$ , therefore any vector can be written in terms of eigenvectors.

Comment: Hint: since the matrix is symmetric, it has a complete set of eigenvectors (that are mutally orthogonal).  Write $x$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be a real number and $v$ be a unit vector such that $a=v^TAv=\max_{x^Tx=1}x^TAx$. Then $P=aI-A$ is positive semidefinite (because it is real symmetric and $x^TPx\ge0$ for every vector $x$). However, [from $v^TPv=0$, one can infer that $Pv=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3730855). Therefore $Av=av$, i.e., $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. It must be the largest among all eigenvalues of $A$, because for every unit eigenvector $x$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we have $\lambda=x^TAx\le a$.

Comment: @FreeZe I am not sure what you are getting at. If you pick an **orthonormal** eigenbasis $u_1,\ldots,u_n$, then $x=\sum_k\langle x,u_k\rangle u_k$. Hence $Ax=\sum_k\lambda_k\langle x,u_k\rangle u_k$ and $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\sum_k\lambda_k\langle x,u_k\rangle^2\le\lambda_\max\sum_k\langle x,u_k\rangle^2=\lambda_\max$. Clearly equality holds when $x$ is a unit vector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue of $A$. Now we are done.

Answer (score 1):

$x^TAx=\langle x, Ax\rangle$ (the standard dot product)$\le |x||Ax|=|Ax|$. So the maximum of $x^TAx$ does not exceed the operator norm of $A$ which is the maximal absolute value of an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take an orthonormal eigenbasis, which exists by the spectral theorem, the problem will boil down to the following: if $(a_1, \ldots, a_n), (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ with $\sum a_i^2=1$ and $\lambda_{\max}=\max{\lambda_i}$, then $\sum \lambda_i a_i^2 \leq \sum \lambda_{\max} a_i^2 \leq \lambda_{\max}$, which holds because $a_i^2\geq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Your proof is in fact what is used for defining "Rayleigh quotient".

Comment: How can we promise orthogonal basis ? I know that eigenvectors from different eigenspaces (corresponding to different eigenvalues), indeed will be orthogonal. But is it correct even when the matrix has, say, 1 eigenvalue?

Comment: @FreeZe If you have a basis for one eigenspace, Grahm-Schmidt lets you find an orthonormal basis for that eigenspace (since any linear combination of eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue are still eigenvectors).

Comment: @FreeZe Also, remember that $A$ being symmetric implies $A$ is diagonalisable. So, if you have only one eigenspace, $A = \lambda I$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Any orthonormal basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$ will be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, in this case!

Comment: Is there a way to continue my attempt? (I edited the post)

Comment: @FreeZe No, because you are starting from the assumption that x is an eigenvector, and you either need to start from it being an arbitrary vector or the vector which maximizes the quantity.